# Literature Request: how does the house quality distribution change endogenously over time?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, housing

Is there existing literature on how the distribution of housing quality changes with time? For example, literature saying "using 2000 as a baseline distribution $X$, the housing quality distribution is $1.2X$ in years when GDP is rising and $0.8X$ in years when GDP is decreasing." This is of course very naive, but hopefully it gets my point across. Perhaps housing price distribution could be used as a proxy for house quality, as there may not be data on the latter.

Answer (score 2):

A paper of interest but it is mostly about trend changes in quality and not business cycle fluctuations:

> This paper employs a new national data set to estimate constant
>   quality dwelling prices for four regions of the country. The data set,
>   collected by the National Association of Realtors, provides sale
>   prices, locations, and characteristics of 5581 dwellings sold during
>   the years 1986–1992 inclusive. The paper provides the first national
>   hedonic analysis based upon transaction prices of sample dwellings.
>   The estimated equation implies that more than half of dwelling price
>   increases during the period resulted from quality improvements in
>   dwellings.

New Hedonic Estimates of Regional Constant Quality House Prices ([Millsa and Simenauerb (1996)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009411909690011X))

Because housing is a long lived asset and it is somewhat unusual to significantly change the size of a house after it is built we could explore your question with the quantity and quality of new housing, assuming existing housing is largely unchanged. The [US Census's New Residential Construction Survey](http://www.census.gov/construction/nrc/about_the_surveys/soc.html) has rich information about new housing. For example, on [Characteristics of New Single-Family Houses Sold](http://www.census.gov/construction/chars/sold.html) one can see many attributes of new houses including size, bedrooms, bathrooms, number sold, and much more. The Median and Average Square Feet of Floor Area in New Single-Family Houses Sold by Location table goes back annually to 1978. So you could compare it with RGDP per capita to get an idea of how this varies with wages.
[image]